# How to use SLIM by default template language instead ERB in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, slim-lang

I need to use Slim-rails in all my Rails projects. How to use Slim-rails by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this to generate your rails project

```
rails new myapp -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
```

choose 3 option at beggining of wizard and later will be option about Template engine

besides slim it has many neat options to speedup your rails project setup

Comment: no wizard shows up. couldn't connect SLL_certificate returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html

Rails Application Templates